# PSQL Table Date Format

Tags: postgresql

I have a journal that creates new timestamps of the current date whenever you post a new entry.

CREATE TABLE posts (
id SERIAL,
postingDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
content VARCHAR(255)
);

With this table my date comes out looking like this: 2021-09-02T07:00:00.000Z.

How can I format the date so it would look like September 2nd, 2021 or something cleaner? I've looked at a bunch of links but I can't get them to work. I wonder if Express is doing something behind the scenes.

Thanks

Comment: Spend some time here [Date/Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html), in particular 8.5.2. Date/Time Output. Though I would read the entire at least a couple of times as it will answer a good many questions. As to formatting see [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) in particular `to_char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_char` for date formatting.

Here example -  `Select to_char(yourDate,'month dd, yyyy') from YourTable`

output -

```
september 03, 2021
```

Comment: How would that look like when creating my Table?

Comment: @Brixsta If i create your table and using your date format so result will be same  - september 03, 2021

Comment: `date`s are not stored formatted, they are stored in a binary format. The formatted `date` you see when you retrieve it is based on the `DateStyle` setting or if you want to override that by using `to_char`. I pointed you at the doc links that explain this in my comment to your question.  Take some time and read through them, it will save you asking a lot of these types of question here.